# jQuery 'this' legacy scoping

Tags: jquery, drupal, scope, this, legacy

I'm trying to back-port a slideshow I wrote in jQuery 1.6 to work in Drupal, which you may or may not know is "locked" to jQuery 1.3 at present (I know, it's retarded).

I'm having a problem with scope though, as jQuery 1.3's `$(this)` model isn't as robust or helpful as it is in more modern releases.

Here's the code that's breaking:

```
var $controls   = $('a.controls', $frame);

$controls.click( function() {

  var $clicked = $(this);

  // ...

}
```

The `a.controls` expression results in a collection of two objects within `$controls` as expected. But when jQuery 1.3 encouters the `$(this)` assignment, it's throwing the following error:

> this[0].ownerDocument is null

Does anyone know why it's doing this, and how I can fix or work around it?

Comment: Drupal 6 is not 'locked' to version 1.3 at all...some of the core js files just rely on 1.3.2. If you can do without those core js files then you can put whatever version of jQuery in that you want. You should also be very aware that jQuery 1.6 moved the goalposts a fair bit and so getting it to work with any major system will be a nightmare until that system upgrades to use the latest version.

Comment: It might be simpler to just load a second version of jQuery and use it only with your slideshow. Though of course it's yet another file that must be downloaded.

Comment: @Clive I'm not prepared to compromise Core; that seems like a bad idea - purely from a maintenance point-of-view - and my users need these features to make the experience of administering the site easier and more helpful. Can you tell me if it's possible to add in a second version of jQuery without compromising Core though?

Comment: Oddly enough I've had this question in my head for the last day or so and I think there is a solution, I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

That’s probably not where the error is happening, the `this` context works the same for event callbacks in 1.3 as in the latest version.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hPfZH/2/

- Are you sure the `$frame` context is correct?
- Are you using inline
  click events on the `$controls` that can add conflict?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think this is going to get done is with a small hack of the jquery_update module. You need to replace the jquery.min.js (or jquery.js if you're not using the minimised version) file in sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace with the latest jQuery version, then make the alterations to the `jquery.module` file (around line 59):

```
function jquery_update_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Only do this for pages that have JavaScript on them.
  if (!empty($variables['scripts'])) {

    // ADD THESE TWO LINES BEFORE THE REST OF THE CODE
    if (preg_match('/^\/admin[\/]*.*/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { return; }
    if (preg_match('/^\/batch[\/]*.*/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { return; }
```

That will basically tell jquery_update to only replace the javascript on non-admin and non-batch pages, which should serve your purpose. There may be other paths you need to add to that check depending on your needs.

I haven't tested this but in theory it will work, unfortunately I can't comment as to whether AHAH (Drupal's lame attempt at an AJAX framework) will work with the later version of jQuery on non-admin pages.

Hope you get this sorted it's a very annoying problem :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't seem to work for me. I followed all your instructions (inc. modifying [jquery_update.module] as above), but I'm now getting "p,a,c,k,e,r" errors from jQuery 1.6.4... so I don't think I can do this. Appreciate your help though!

Comment: That's a shame, I think one of the main problems is that quite a lot changed in jQuery 1.6...if you can get away with using 1.5.2 it might work but it's pot luck really!

Comment: Just an addition to that last comment (couldn't let this one go for some reason!), [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1067290) on Drupal.org has people claiming they've got jQuery 1.5.1 working with Drupal 6 using similar methods to that mentioned in the answer above...maybe that will help you sort it?

Answer (score -1):

This may not answer the question but may help you with the problem.

With drupal module [jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) you can choose the jquery version in drupal.

Comment: No you can't, it updates either Drupal 6 to 1.3.2 or Drupal 7 to 1.5.2. The fact that the OP is using Drupal 6 and already using jQuery 1.3 should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: You can just simply add your questioned drupal version into the modules directory instead of the jquery version which is in there and I think it is what people do